# Why does authorization fails when I publish on IIS in aspnet core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have used aspnet core identity for login functionality in my webapp. I have published my webapp on IIS. It loads perfectly but when I enter username and password and navigate to action methods bearing **authorize** attribute the applications fails. But renaming the action methods with **AllowAnonymous** attribute solves my issue!!

Note: The application runs perfect with authorize attribute when I debug it locally(localhost) 
how could I fix this?

startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using OnlineExam.Models.LoginModel;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using OnlineExam.Models.CandidateLogin;

namespace OnlineExam
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
            services.AddIdentity<OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel.ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = default;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            })
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Models.UserAccountModel.OnlineExamDBContext>();

            //services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                           .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                           .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddDbContext<OnlineExamDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<OnlineExam.Models.AdminQuestionModel.OnlineExamDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<CandidateLoginDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<OnlineExam.Models.CandidateExam.CandidateExamDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoginConnection")));
            services.AddScoped<OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel.OnlineExamDBContext>();
            //services.AddScoped<OnlineExam.Controllers.AdminQuestionController>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            //if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //{
            //    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            //    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            //    app.UseHsts();
            //}
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}



using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace OnlineExam.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class UserAccountsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly OnlineExamDBContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel.ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel.ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        List<ApplicationUser> userList = new List<ApplicationUser>();

        public UserAccountsController(OnlineExamDBContext context, UserManager<OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel.ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel.ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        // GET: UserAccounts
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.ApplicationUser.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: UserAccounts/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var userAccount = await _context.ApplicationUser
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserAccountId == id);
            if (userAccount == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(userAccount);
        }

        // GET: UserAccounts/Create
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var viewmodel = new ApplicationUser();
            return View(viewmodel);
        }

        // POST: UserAccounts/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ApplicationUser userModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                bool userCheck = IsUserExists(userModel.UserName);
                if (userCheck == false)
                {
                    var user = new OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel.ApplicationUser();
                    user = userModel;
                    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.UserPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return Logout();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("","Username already exist");
                }

            }
            return View(userModel);
        }

        // GET: UserAccounts/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var userAccount = await _context.ApplicationUser.FindAsync(id);
            if (userAccount == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(userAccount);
        }

        // POST: UserAccounts/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("UserAccountId,UserName,UserPassword,UserFullName,UserGender,UserPriviledge,UserDesignation,UserDepartment,UserMailId,UserAddress,UserMobileNo,UserPhoto,UserQualification")] UserAccount userAccount)
        {
            if (id != userAccount.UserAccountId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(userAccount);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!UserAccountExists(userAccount.UserAccountId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(userAccount);
        }

        // GET: UserAccounts/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var userAccount = await _context.ApplicationUser
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserAccountId == id);
            if (userAccount == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(userAccount);
        }

        // POST: UserAccounts/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var userAccount = await _context.ApplicationUser.FindAsync(id);
            _context.ApplicationUser.Remove(userAccount);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool UserAccountExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.ApplicationUser.Any(e => e.UserAccountId == id);
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(ApplicationUser login)
        {
            ///var user = new OnlineExam.Models.UserAccountModel.ApplicationUser { UserName = login.UserName };
            //TempData["user"] = user;
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login.UserName, login.UserPassword, true, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                 var userData = from x in _context.ApplicationUser.Where(x => x.UserName == login.UserName).ToList()
                                    select new { x.UserFullName, x.Email, x.UserAddress ,x.UserName
                                    ,x.UserPhoto ,x.UserMobileNo,x.UserGender,x.UserQualification,
                                    x.UserDepartment,x.UserDesignation,x.UserPriviledge,x.UserAccountId};

                //List<ApplicationUser> userList = new List<ApplicationUser>();
                foreach (var item in userData)
                {
                    userList.Add(new ApplicationUser 
                    { UserFullName =item.UserFullName, UserAccountId= item.UserAccountId,UserName=item.UserName,
                      Email=item.Email,UserDepartment=item.UserDepartment,UserGender=item.UserGender, 
                      UserPriviledge=item.UserPriviledge, UserPhoto=item.UserPhoto, UserAddress=item.UserAddress
                    });
                    //userList.Add(new ApplicationUserReplica { UserAccountId = item.UserAccountId });
                }
                //List<ApplicationUserReplica> userList= new List<ApplicationUserReplica>();
                //userList.Add(new ApplicationUserReplica { UserFullName = userData.Select(x => x.UserFullName).ToString()});
                // userList.Add(new ApplicationUserReplica { UserAccountId =Convert.ToInt32(userData.Select(x => x.UserAccountId)) });

                var sdata=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList);
                TempData["userData"] = sdata;
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginInfo));
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please enter you username and password correctly");
            }
            return View(login);
        }
        public  bool IsUserExists(string userName)
        {
            int c=_context.ApplicationUser.Where(x => x.UserName == userName).Count();
            if (c >= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult LoginInfo()
        {
            userList=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ApplicationUser>>(TempData["userData"].ToString());
            TempData.Keep();
            foreach(var item in userList)
            {
                TempData["userId"] = item.UserAccountId;
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide some code/configuration, at least the relevant configurations in Startup/Program classes. Could be anything form redirection issue, no forwarded headers to some exception to cookie issues. Be more specific, post what you efforts and investigations you done so far

Comment: @Tseng here is the code!!

Comment: Have you tried registering a new user after the site has been deployed on IIS?

Comment: i tried registering new one..but cud not fix the issue.. @BilalAhmed

Comment: it throws this error wheni try to log in This page isn’t working www.xyz.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: `UseHttpsRedirection` behind certain reverse proxy configurations can be problematic. But if it thows 500, you must have some exception message you are not posting here?